# How to enable WPML in BuddyPress Multilingual Plugin in a single website?

Tags: plugins, buddypress, multi-language

There is a plugin called [BuddyPress Multilingual](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-multilingual/) version 1.4.0. I installed this plugin in wordpress. But I can't see it anywhere in the admin panel nor in plugins. There is very little documentation else where on the website.

**Where are the options for that plugin?**

If this is a broken plugin then **what is the alternative to implement multilingual option?**

I prefer to make a blog in wordpress which can support multilanguages. It's better if a plugin is able to translate the post or page after selecting a language on the wordpress editor.

Answer (score 1):

On [BuddyPress Multilingual](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-multilingual/) you can read:

> This plugin requires WPML. It uses WPML's language API and hooks to BuddyPress to make it multilingual.

You need to have WPML installed for BuddyPress Multilingual to function correctly.
Also, Buddypress Multilingual is for Buddypress sites. If you want to make your Wordpress site multilingual, my advice is to use [WPML](http://wpml.org/).

Comment: Is the buddy press and WMPL are PAID or NOT?

Comment: WPML is paid, but the BuddyPress Multilingual extension is free.